# ImportError: No module named selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to run some python code from Visual Studio Code and I'm getting this error all the time:ImportError: No module named selenium.

I've tryed to install again and again and I get this showing that it is already installed:

Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /home/dpascoa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)

I saw somewhere that I needed to install geckodriver for this to work, but I can't find a way to put this working, even after trying to install geckodriver.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Open a command prompt (not VS - WHY???) and type "python3". When you get the python prompt, type "import Selenium" and see what error (if any) you get. It sounds like VS is running a separate python environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to install selenium webdriver in my Ubuntu 16.04 system for python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041541/i-want-to-install-selenium-webdriver-in-my-ubuntu-16-04-system-for-python)

Comment: I tried but when import webdriver nothing happens...
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium'
>>> import selenium
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> import Selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium'
>>>